# Adding attribute class in table row not working

Tags: 6, theming

If I add any other attribute like class2 then it works but 'class' is not working. If you see below, there is a line: `'class' =>'hellodssdddsdsdsds'`. What I want is that this class should be added in tr like: `<tr class="hellodssdddsdsdsds" >...</tr>;`

If I use class2 instead of class in in below code it works and the table row now correctly contains attribute class2: `<tr class2="hellodssdddsdsdsds">...<tr>` but not when adding class word. How to add a class as per the `theme_table()` api function?

```
$donation_records = & $form['show_donation']['donation_records'];

if(user_access(AnuDonationUtilities::APPROVE_DONATION_DETAILS or user_access(AnuDonationUtilities::ENTER_DONATION_DETAILS)))
{
foreach(element_children($donation_records) as $key)
{          
    if( ctype_digit("$key"))
    {
        $state_mask = $donation_records[$key]['hidden_current_state_mask']['#value'];

        $class_attrib = "";

        if($state_mask & AnuDonationSingleRecordState::IS_CANCELLED)
        {
            $class_attrib .= " an-dr-cancelled ";
        }
        if($state_mask & AnuDonationSingleRecordState::IS_VERIFIED)
        {
            $class_attrib .= " an-dr-isverified ";
        }
        if($state_mask & AnuDonationSingleRecordState::NEEDS_VERIFICATION)
        {
            $class_attrib .= " an-dr-needs-verification ";
        }

        $class_attrib = "an-dr-needs-verification";

        $row = array(
            'data' => array(
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["sno"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["op"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["cancel"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["verify"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["donation_amount"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["donated_by"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["donated_by_uid"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["donation_details"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["comments"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["donor_comments"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["payment_medium"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["create_date"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($donation_records[$key]["created_by"]) ),
            ),
            'class' =>'hellodssdddsdsdsds',
        );

        if($state_mask != 0)
        {
            $row['class'] = array($class_attrib);
        }

       $rows[] = $row;
    }
}  
    $header = array(
    t('Sno'),
    t('Op'),
    t('Cancel(ed)'),
    t('Verify'),
    t('Donation Amount'),
    t('Donated By'),
    t('Donor Username'),
    t('Donation Details'),
    t('Comments'),
    t('Donor Comments'),
    t('Payment Method'),
    t('Dated'),
    t('Updated By'),
  );

 $output = '<fieldset><legend>'.t('Donation Contribution Details').theme('table', $header, $rows);

 //Now format the table to add new records

 $rows = array();

 foreach(element_children($form['add_new_records']) as $key)
 {
     if( ctype_digit("$key"))
    {
        $row = array(

            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["sno"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["donation_amount"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["donated_by"]) ),
            array( 'data' =>drupal_render ($form['add_new_records'][$key]["donated_by_uid"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["donation_details"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["comments"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["donor_comments"]) ),
            array( 'data' => drupal_render($form['add_new_records'][$key]["payment_medium"]) ),               
        );

       $rows[] = $row;
    }

 }

 $header = array(        
    t('Sno'),
    t('Donation Amount'),
    t('Donated By'),
    t('Donor Username'),
    t('Donation Details'),
    t('Comments'),
    t('Donor Comments'),
    t('Payment Method'),        
  );

 $output .= '<fieldset><legend>'.t('Enter Donation Details').theme('table', $header, $rows);

 $output .= drupal_render($form);

 return $output;
}//if
```

Comment: Please can you provide a little more background on what you are trying to do?

Comment: depending on type of row, I want to attach class attribute with tr's. For example for deleted data I want a class attribute like "deleted-data". I'm doing as per http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/6

Comment: How is your $header variable defined?

Comment: I've updated the code. Everything is working fine except for the class id which I'm unable to add.

Comment: How is your $rows variable defined? I see $row, but not $rows.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working". What do you expect? What do you get? Where is the difference between the two?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did  a silly mistake in the code which was overwriting class value:  if($state_mask != 0)         {             $row['class'] = array($class_attrib);         }

Answer (score 1):

The 'class' element in a render array should be an array, not a string. So your code:

```
'class' =>'hellodssdddsdsdsds',
```

should be:

```
'class' => array('hellodssdddsdsdsds'),
```

When you define a new element in the array, 'class2', there is nothing dictating what type of variable this new element should be, so it works without any problems.